# Wordpress on a subdirectory of Laravel - Wordpress pretty permalinks inner page shows laravel

Tags: wordpress, laravel, .htaccess, url, permalinks

I read lots of discussions about this and found no solution. I have a Laravel web app and added a Wordpress blog (`Blog`) in a subdirectory `public`. This is what my .htaccess looks like within the public folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

And this is my .htaccess in wordpress root directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /Blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

If I use the plain permalinks, everything works fine. If I use any other type of permalink it adds index.php to the URL and shows me the Laravel app. The permalinks adds the index.php in the permalinks page:

[look here, currently all this is well but if i use any type of permalinks no(plain) it's not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaUZQ.png)

The funny thing is, if I choose the post name permalink with the %postname% in it, the URL is:

```
http://localhost:8000/blog/postname/
```

and I see the laravel app, but the same URL with the admin
(`http://localhost:8000/blog/wp-admin/`) or any other admin pages, works fine.

I really don't want to have to use ugly permalinks here.

Is there a solution?

NB - as you can see on the url, the site is currently on localhost using APACHE in kali linux

Answer (score 1):

The conditions in the Laravel rewrite are probably matching. Requests to WordPress won't match a file or directory and will be rewritten by the rule:

```
# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Try adding a condition to not rewrite for the blog directory:

```
# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```